# How to find/replace element in field with Field Calculator

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator

I just want to perform the following operation done in Matlab into the Field Calculator using Python:

```
p(p==0) = 0.001 ; p(p == 1) = 0.999; 
tVar = .5*log(p ./ (1 - p))
```

the operation consists of a Logit transformation:

1. Find 0's and 1's and replace with .001 and .999 respectively, and
2. Perform the second calculation with logarithms

I've tried the following for 1) in Python to no avail:

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def iLogit(a):
  return [.0001 if x==0 else x for x in a]
```

Any help please?

Comment: A better formula for this purpose--because it would be a monotonic transformation of the data, which yours is not--would simply add a small constant to each of p and 1-p, as in `0.5 * log((p + 0.001) / (1 - p + 0.001))`. If your value of p is found as a ratio of counts, you would do even better by recomputing those ratios after adding a small "start" value (such as 1/6) to both the numerator and the denominator. This will prevent p from ever attaining 0 or 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a Python parser:

Pre-Logic Script Code:

```
def switch(x):
    if x == 0:
        x = 0.001
    elif x == 1:
        x = 0.999
    tVar = 0.5 * math.log(x / (1 - x))
    return tVar
```

In the Codeblock:

y=

```
switch(!x!)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### updated answer

As you use a list (`return [.0001 if x==0 else x for x in a]`) and a a logit funtion (thanks [whuber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/664/whuber), I  had completely forgotten this function in my first answer: real values strictly between 0 and 1.):

in Matlab/Octave:

```
 p=[1,1,0.5,0.6,0,0.4,1];
 p(p==0) = 0.001 ; p(p == 1) = 0.999;
 disp(p)
 0.9990    0.9990    0.5000    0.6000    0.0010    0.4000    0.9990 
 tVar = .5*log(p ./ (1 - p));
 disp(tvar)
 3.4534    3.4534         0    0.2027   -3.4534   -0.2027    3.4534
```

In Python:

```
from math import log #natural logarithm
p=[1,1,0.5,0.6,0,0.4,1]
# with conditional list comprehension
p =[(0.001 if x==0 else (0.999 if x==1  else x)) for x in p]
print p
[0.999, 0.999, 0.5, 0.6, 0.001, 0.4, 0.999]
tVar = [.5*log(x/(1-x)) for x in p]
print tVar
[3.4533773893242765, 3.4533773893242765, 0.0, 0.2027325540540821, -3.453377389324277, -0.20273255405408214, 3.4533773893242765]
```

So, we can write the function (result as a list):

```
def iLogit(a):
    replace = [(0.001 if x==0 else (0.9999 if x==1  else x)) for x in a]
    return [.5*log(x/(1-x)) for x in replace]
```

---

( Original answer with errors in the values for  logit transformation )

in Matlab:

```
p=[1,2,0,1,0,2,1,1];
p(p==0) = 0.001 ; p(p == 1) = 0.999;
disp(p):
0.9990000   2.0000000   0.0010000   0.9990000   0.0010000   2.0000000 0.9990000   0.9990000
tVar = .5*log(p ./ (1 - p));
disp(tvar)
3.45338 + 0.00000i   0.34657 + 1.57080i  -3.45338 + 0.00000i   3.45338 + 0.00000i  -3.45338 + 0.00000i   0.34657 + 1.57080i   3.45338 + 0.00000i   3.45338 + 0.00000i
```

In Python:

```
from math import log #natural logarithm
p=[1,2,0,1,0,2,1,1]
# with conditional list comprehension
p =[(0.001 if x==0 else (0.999 if x==1  else x)) for x in p]
print p
[0.999, 2, 0.001, 0.999, 0.001, 2, 0.999, 0.999]
tVar = [.5*log(x/(1-x)) for x in p]
```

So, in theory:

```
def iLogit(a):
    replace = [(0.001 if x==0 else (0.9999 if x==1  else x)) for x in a]
    return [.5*log(x/(1-x)) for x in replace]
```

Why in theory ? Because of the logarithm of negative numbers: you can only compute the logarithm of a positive number in Python only.

```
 x = 3
 print .5*log(x/(1-x)) # or print .5*log(3/(1-3))
 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ValueError: math domain error

 # with numpy
 print .5*numpy.log(x/(1-x))
 Warning: invalid value encountered in log
 nan
```

If you want the same result as Matlab (complex number), you must use the [cmath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) module

```
import cmath
x = 0.999
print .5*(cmath.log(x/(1-x)))
(3.45337738932+0j)
```

Don't forget the problem of floating Point Arithmetic: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in Python.)

Comment: A logit transformation is intended to be applied only to real values strictly between 0 and 1.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know ArcPy, so my answer. Then my function `iLogit(a):`works without problem.

Comment: Whether this is implemented in ArcPy or not is irrelevant.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit, for instance.

Comment: Thanks, whuber, I had completely forgotten this function...

Answer (score 1):

Try with...

*Pre-Logic Script Code:*

```
def iLogit(x):
  if x==0:
    x=0.001
  elif x==1:
    x=0.999
  tVar=0.5*math.log(x/(1-x))
  return tVar
```

**EDIT (compact version):**

```
def iLogit(x):
    x = .001 if x==0 else .999 if x==1 else x
    return .5*math.log(x/(1-x))
```